# Integer Number too large in java int for the value 08 , but when I pass just 8 or 11,12,13 it is just fine

Tags: java, int

Employee("Helen",16000,1965,08,03),compiler is throwing the error that integer number is too large for value : 08 but compiler has no problem with value 11 or just 8.

```
      import java.util.*;
      class Employee{
          private String name;
          private double salary;
          private Date hireDay;

              public Employee(String n, double s,int year, int month, int day){
                  name = n;
                  salary = s;
                  GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month-1,day);
                  hireDay = calendar.getTime();
              }
              public String getName(){
                  return name; 
              }   
              public double getSalary(){
                  return salary;
              }   
              public Date getHireDay(){
                  return hireDay; 
              }   

              public void raiseSalary(double byPercent){
                  double raise = salary * byPercent / 100;
                  salary += raise;

              }

      }

      public class EmployeeTest{
          public static void main(String[] args){

         Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];
          staff[0] = new Employee("Jack",15000,1992,03,07);
          staff[1] = new Employee("James",18000,1987,05,02);
    >>    staff[2] = new Employee("Helen",16000,1965,08,03);
```

// This is the problem.When I pass 08 it throws an error when I pass 08 or some two digit number it is find
                }

```
Output :

    [shadow@localhost java]$ javac EmployeeTest.java 
    EmployeeTest.java:37: error: integer number too large: 08
        staff[2] = new Employee("Helen",16000,1965,08,03);
                                                   ^
    1 error
    [shadow@localhost java]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because, in Java, numbers that start with a leading `0` (like your `08`) are treated as octal (base 8).  And there is no 8 in octal.

(By definition octal only uses the digits 0-7)

As an experiment, you can try `07` or `011` and see that they work, or try `08` or `09` and see that they don't work.

Comment: But I passed the data type as int. Why java is treating 08 as octal ?

Comment: in java a leading `0` is understood to be an octal digit